# Convert LONG format to DATE without a function

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle18c

The column `HIGH_VALUE` has data similar to below, of type `LONG`, and always has the same length:

```
TIMESTAMP' 2019-01-30 00:00:00'
```

How can I convert it to a `DATE` type without using a function?

My overall goal is to create a result set which can then be used as an inner query for other aggregations. For example, I would like to be able to sum the number of rows over a year according to the date produced by converting the `HIGH_VALUE` column to a date.

I have only read permissions on this database and therefore cannot create functions. I've seen other solutions on StackOverflow and other sites, but they all require creating a function.

`ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS` is a standard built-in Oracle table and therefore I'm not including the table structure. In case that's an issue, please let me know and I will create an example table.

An example query and the data one row that results from this query follows. Note that I cannot create tables on this database so I will also need an a method that works without creating a temporary table.

```
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,PARTITION_NAME,HIGH_VALUE,NUM_ROWS) 
VALUES ('TO','TN','SYS_P201709','TIMESTAMP'' 2019-01-30 00:00:00''',5053133);

SELECT TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE, NUM_ROWS
from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS;
```

Comment: There's [this XPath solution on DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210024/557)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Oracle 12c you could still use function but defined inline:

```
WITH FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
    -- logic here
    RETURN p_id;
END;
SELECT with_function(id)
FROM   your_table
```

Related: [WITH Clause Enhancements in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1)

Answer (score 2):

For the conversion of a `LONG` type ( `HIGH_VALUE` ) to `TIMESTAMP`, 
One option is to use dynamic sql and perform your insert through an anonymous block. No Procedure or function is required.

```
DECLARE
     tstamp TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
     FOR rec IN ( SELECT table_owner,table_name,partition_name,high_value,num_rows
                  FROM all_tab_partitions
                  WHERE ROWNUM < 5
                ) LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :dt := '
                            || rec.high_value
                            || '; END;'
             USING OUT tstamp;  --assign the long to an external timestamp variable
     INSERT INTO export_table (
               table_owner,table_name,partition_name,high_value,num_rows
          ) VALUES (rec.table_owner, 
            rec.table_name, rec.partition_name, tstamp, rec.num_rows
          );

     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

AS @APC commented, There's also a [**solution using Pure SQL**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210024/136182), which 
uses a slightly complex Xml expression.

Comment: Why not `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( rec.table_owner, rec.table_name, rec.partition_name, tstamp, rec.num_rows )` rather than hard-coded literals?

Comment: Is it possible to re-work this solution to avoid creating a temporary table? I cannot create tables on this database. I've added a clarification to my post now so that should be more evident. The original post did say that I have read-only access to this database.

Comment: @MT0 : Due to laziness :-). I pasted now from your comments LOL ! Thanks

Comment: @Bobby : What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I presumed you want to insert records into another table as implied from your code. Tell us what do you want with the values read from `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS`

Comment: @KaushikNayak Good question! I thought I would ask only about the technical issue that I'm having. I would like to use the results of this query as a sub-query such that I can perform other aggregations. i.e. SUM of num_rows over a year according to the date in high_value.

Comment: @Bobby : Sure, then have a look at the Pure SQL solution which APC suggested and linked now in my answer. Always remember to provide sufficiently clear information as to what you want to ultimately accomplish in your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I've tried the different variants in the linked solution, but always have this error: `ORA-00904: "DBMS_XMLGEN"."GETXMLTYPE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"` I thought my database was 12c, but it turns out that it's 18c. Anyways, this should be backwards compatible, right?

Answer (score 1):

Combining the [pure SQL solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210024/557) from [APC's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771287/convert-long-format-to-date-without-a-function#comment100098727_56771287) with the enhancements in Oracle 12 to allow functions to be declared in `WITH` clauses and [Kaushik Nayak's method of using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to convert the string value to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56771607/1509264) then you can get this:

**Oracle Setup - Test Table & Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE EXPORT_TABLE (
  TABLE_OWNER     VARCHAR2(30),
  TABLE_NAME      VARCHAR2(30),
  PARTITION_NAME  VARCHAR2(30),
  HIGH_VALUE      LONG,
  NUM_ROWS        INTEGER
); 

INSERT INTO EXPORT_TABLE VALUES ( 'TO', 'TN', 'PN', 'TIMESTAMP ''2019-06-26 12:34:56''', 12345 );
```

**Query**:

```
WITH FUNCTION clobToDate( value IN CLOB ) RETURN DATE
  IS
    ts DATE;
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ts := ' || value || '; END;' USING OUT ts;
    RETURN ts;
  END;
SELECT TABLE_OWNER,
       TABLE_NAME,
       PARTITION_NAME,
       clobToDate(
         EXTRACTVALUE(
           dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
             'SELECT high_value'
             || ' FROM  EXPORT_TABLE'
             || ' WHERE TABLE_OWNER    = ''' || t.table_owner || ''''
             || ' AND   TABLE_NAME     = ''' || t.table_name || ''''
             || ' AND   PARTITION_NAME = ''' || t.partition_name || ''''
           ),
           '//text()'
         )
       ) AS HIGH_VALUE,
       NUM_ROWS
FROM   EXPORT_TABLE t;
```

**Output**:

```
TABLE_OWNER | TABLE_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | HIGH_VALUE          | NUM_ROWS
:---------- | :--------- | :------------- | :------------------ | -------:
TO          | TN         | PN             | 2019-06-26 12:34:56 |    12345
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7e9f3fceed9dc0a33f074d3ef60cc28d)*

---

**Update**: If you want to aggregate some columns then:

```
WITH FUNCTION clobToDate( value IN CLOB ) RETURN DATE
  IS
    ts DATE;
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ts := ' || value || '; END;' USING OUT ts;
    RETURN ts;
  END;
SELECT table_owner,
       table_name,
       MAX( high_value ) AS max_high_value,
       SUM( num_rows ) AS total_rows
FROM   (
  SELECT TABLE_OWNER,
         TABLE_NAME,
         PARTITION_NAME,
         clobToDate(
           EXTRACTVALUE(
             dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
               'SELECT high_value'
               || ' FROM  EXPORT_TABLE'
               || ' WHERE TABLE_OWNER    = ''' || t.table_owner || ''''
               || ' AND   TABLE_NAME     = ''' || t.table_name || ''''
               || ' AND   PARTITION_NAME = ''' || t.partition_name || ''''
             ),
             '//text()'
           )
         ) AS HIGH_VALUE,
         NUM_ROWS
  FROM   EXPORT_TABLE t
)
GROUP BY table_owner, table_name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c2cb6d6d7eb2646f633bb6d8c7954451)*

Comment: This has a nice formatting, but is there a way to do something similar with standard SQL such that I can use the result set for further aggregations? I clarified this requirement recently so it could be that you started your answer before I added my clarifications.

Comment: The demo in db<>fiddle returns a standard result set which is exactly what I've asked for. However, when I try it locally, and replace `EXPORT_TABLE`  with `(SELECT TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE, NUM_ROWS FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_OWNER='TO' AND TABLE_NAME='TO') ` , I get this error: ` ORA-00904: "DBMS_XMLGEN"."GETXMLTYPE": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" `   I thought my database was 12c, but it turns out that it's 18c. Could that play a role? Your demo however in db<>fiddle also uses 18c.

Comment: @Bobby [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8a089a92405d6b1cd5c8a8c782d0581) works for `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS`. There were two places to change `EXPORT_TABLE` to `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS`. If it still does not work for you then it is probably something to do with your local setup and you might not have permissions granted to execute the `DBMS_XMLGEN` package; this is not something that we can help resolve as it is dependent on what your DBA allows and you should talk to them about it.

Comment: Indeed, I did forget to replace the first instance. Now 've replaced that entire line with the following using literal quoting. 'm getting an invalid table name error, so there must still be an issue:

             || q'[ FROM  (select TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE, num_rows 
from all_tab_partitions WHERE TABLE_OWNER = 'RSS_ACQ' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TRX_ARQ') ]'

That entire line replaces this one:

               || ' FROM  EXPORT_TABLE'